# составить функцию, которая в одномерном массиве определяет первый от начала отрицательный элемент

Tags: c

составить функцию, которая в одномерном массиве определяет первый от начала отрицательный элемент. в случае нахождения отрицательного числа функция возвращает найденное число, в противном случае возвращает 1. С помощью функции определить в каждой строке матрицы первые отрицательные элементы, которые записать в новый массив, вывести полученный массив.

```
       #include "stdafx.h" 
       #include "stdio.h" 
       #include "conio.h" 
       #include "math.h"

       const int k = 12, l = 14;

       int per_otr(int d[], int *l)
       {
        int otr = 1;
        for (int i = 0; i<*l; i++)
        {
          if (d[i]<0)
          otr = d[i];
        }
        return otr;
      }
      void vvod2(int a[][l], int *n, int *m)
      {
        printf("Vvedite kolichestvo strok:\n");
        scanf("%d", n);
        printf("Vvedite kolichestvo stolbcov:\n");
            scanf("%d", m);
            for (int i = 0; i<*n; i++)
            {
                printf("Vvedite %d stroky:\n", i + 1);
                for (int j = 0; j<*m; j++)
                    scanf("%d", &a[i][j]);
            }
        }
        void vivod(int a[], int t)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<t; i++)
                printf("%d ", a[i]);
        }
        void vivod2(int a[][l], int n, int m)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
                    printf("%d ", a[i][j]);
                printf("\n");
            }
        }
        void perepis(int ar[][l], int a[], int n, int m, int *t)
        {
            *t = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i<n; i++)
                for (int j = 0; j<m; j++)
                    if ((per_otr(ar[j], &n))!=1)
                    {
                        a[*t] = ar[i][j];
                        (*t)++;

                    }
        }

        void swap(int *a, int *b)
        {
            int buf = *a;
            *a = *b;
            *b = buf;
        }

        void sort(int a[], int t)

        {
            for (int i = 0; i<t - 1; i++)
                for (int j = i + 1; j<t; j++)
                    if (a[i]>a[j])
                        swap(&a[i], &a[j]);
        }



        int main()
        {
            int ar[k][l], a[k], n, m, t;
            vvod2(ar, &n, &m);
            printf("Isxodnii massiv:\n");
            vivod2(ar, n, m);
            perepis(ar, a, n, m, &t);
            printf("Chisla  v new massive:\n");
            vivod(a, t);
            printf("\n");
            sort(a, t);
            printf("Otsortirovannie Chisla  v new massive:\n");
            vivod(a, t);
            _getch();
            return 0;
        }
```

Comment: помогите найти ошибку, пожалуйста

Comment: Конкретно в чем ошибка? Какое поведение ожидается и что происходит на самом деле?

Comment: Вопросы с просьбами помочь с отладкой («почему этот код не работает?») должны включать желаемое поведение, конкретную проблему или ошибку и минимальный код для её воспроизведения прямо в вопросе. Вопросы без явного описания проблемы бесполезны для остальных посетителей....

Answer (score 0):

Что делает ваша ф-ция `per_otr`? Она находит отрицательный элемент в строке, которая ей передана? Тогда почему у вас в ф-ции `perepis` ф-ция проходит еще и по столбцам? Вы, по-сути, дважды делаете одно и то же.

Эта ф-ция, по сути, здесь совершенно незачем. Просто замените ее вызов в `perepis` на:

```
if (ar [i][j] < 0)
```

и все будет работать.

Comment: я убрал эту ф-цию из проги и прога теперь выводит все имеющиеся отрицательные числа

Comment: к тому же лучше не обращаться с массивами так, как это делаете вы - вы создаете большой массив, а используете только часть его. Не лучше ли объявлять массив после того, как станет известно количество строк и столбцов?

Comment: Не является ответом на вопрос. Чтобы оставить свои замечания или попросить у автора внести уточнения, оставьте комментарий к соответствующему сообщению. - [Из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/223747)

Comment: отредактировал для большей ясности